# Using multiple indicies to grab values from 2D MATLAB array without returning all combinations

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am trying to get a few values from a 2D matrix

Consider the starting matrix:

```
>> test = randi(10,10)

test =

10     4     8     7    10     4     2     8     4     1
 6     5     6     5     5     2    10     4     7     6
 7     2     5     4     1     1     3     7     6     1
 1     3     3     9     9     5    10     4     6     9
 9     1     8     4     7     2     3     7     3    10
 8    10     3     9     4     8     4     1     3     1
 2     7     1     8    10     4     1    10     5    10
 6    10     8     9     3     9     7     9     3     1
 4     2     7     6     7     8     2     8     9     7
 6    10     8     7     7     6     1     9    10     8
```

What I want to do is grab elements (1,4);(2,5);and(3,6) only

So I try

```
test([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

but that returns all combinations of the two indicies!

```
ans =

 6     3     1
 1     2     4
 8     4     8
```

Without this intermediate step, how do I do what I want in one line?  There must be a way.

I cannot use the intermediate step because in actuality, my matrix is very large and so are my indices lengths so I will run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `sub2ind` as was already pointed out at [mathworks](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/247874-how-to-select-specific-elements-in-a-matrix):

```
test(sub2ind(size(test),[1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
```

**Applied to 3D**

```
test = randi(10,10,10,10);
test(sub2ind(size(test),[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [3,3,3]))
```

Comment: the problem is I'm trying to use this in a 3D array, so I cannot say test(index,3) where index represents the first 2 dimensions.  Do you know a work around that?

Comment: I provided an answer for 3D, please update your question to include the 3D case.